# (Problem 2.21: Algebraic Curves, William Fulton) - Example that guarantees that $\mathfrak{m}_P(V) \not\subset \varphi(\mathfrak{m}_Q(W))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi: V \longrightarrow W$ be a polynomial map between affine varieties, $\tilde{\varphi}: \Gamma(W) \longrightarrow \Gamma(V)$ the coordinate ring homomorphism induced by $\varphi$ and also

$$\mathfrak{m}_P(V) = \{ f \in \mathcal{O}_P (V ); f (P) = 0\} \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \mathfrak{m}_Q(W) = \{ f \in \mathcal{O}_Q (W ); f (Q) = 0\}.$$

It is easy to see that the following inclusion is valid $$\tilde{\varphi}(\mathfrak{m}_Q(W)) \subset \mathfrak{m}_P(V),$$
since taking $a/b \in \mathfrak{m}_Q(W)$ arbitrary, we have $a(Q) = 0$ and, consequently,
$$(\tilde{\varphi}(a))(P) = a(\varphi(P)) = a(Q) = 0.$$
So, $\tilde{\varphi}(a/b) \in \mathfrak{m}_P(V)$. **Can you help me with an example that guarantees that $$\mathfrak{m}_P(V) \not\subset \tilde{\varphi}(\mathfrak{m}_Q(W))?$$**

P.S: More information about notations: [http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ewfulton/CurveBook.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concrete example is taking $V=W=\mathbb{A}_1$, and $f\colon \mathbb{A}_1 \to \mathbb{A}_1$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$. You can verify that the corresponding map of the coordinate rings is $\overline{f}\colon k[x] \to k[x], x \mapsto x^2$. This way, and as $\mathfrak{m}_0=(x)$, we get that $\overline{f}(\mathfrak{m}_0)=(x^2) \subsetneq (x)=\mathfrak{m}_0$.